# XeLaTeX: how do I make paper to be exactly the size of the content?

Tags: graphics, xetex

In LaTeX I can make a document to be exactly the size of the content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active]{preview}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
  \[
  \pi = \sqrt{12}\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-3)^{-k}}{2k+1}
  \]
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

And compile that with

```
latex foo.tex
dvipng -T tight -D 231.26 -o foo.png foo.dvi
```

it makes an image exactly the size of the content (formula).

How do I get the same with XeLaTeX?

I need that because I use inkscape export to latex for images -- and sometimes I need the images as standalone files, not inside a tex document.

**Edit**:

Here's a full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\missingfigure[figwidth=6cm]{}

\end{document}
```

I actually use

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \def\svgwidth{1\columnwidth}
  \input{2dSqFermi_2el.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

as a figure (that's what "inkscape export to latex" is about) -- but that's not important. So in the initial MWE I've just used formula. I see that the given answers already solve that.

Comment: Question is not understandable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Method 1 (Using `standalone` document class)

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass[preview]{standalone}
  \begin{document}
  $
    \displaystyle
    \pi = \sqrt{12}\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-3)^{-k}}{2k+1}
  $
  \end{document}
  ```
- Method 2 (Using `geometry` package)

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \newsavebox\IBox
  \savebox\IBox{\raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle\pi = \sqrt{12}\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-3)^{-k}}{2k+1}$}}
  \usepackage[paperwidth=\wd\IBox,paperheight=\ht\IBox,margin=0pt]{geometry}

  \begin{document}
  \noindent\usebox\IBox
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Another posibility is to use the magnífic Latexit program.

Comment: @jpayansomet: Do you understand the questioner's question? I don't. :-)

Comment: I end up using Your standalone approach.

Answer (score 3):

Take the look into the [`standalone`](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) package.

Example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \pi = \sqrt{12}\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-3)^{-k}}{2k+1}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Yours solution works too sir. It's sad I can't accept multiple answers.